# Understanding 警戒と注意<に>

Tags: grammar, particle-に

> 士道は真剣な表情でうなずきかえした。それはそうだ。士道は六喰に幾度となく殺されかけているのである。警戒と注意**に**、し過ぎということはないだろう。

I understand the last sentence means he can’t be too careful. But how should I make sense of this bold に? If it was を, then it’s easier to understand.

Comment: 「～に（名詞）はない」is a common pattern, I'm not sure を even works here

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the comment, this に can be understood as the common place indicator and 警戒と注意 as an abstract place. Essentially it means the same as に関して here. So literally, *In the realm of caution and attention, doing too much does not exist*.

Using を is possible, but then inserting a comma looks odd. It should be 警戒と注意をしすぎということはないだろう. This is probably because the verb-object relationship is felt stronger than topic-verb relationship in case of using に.